# Hide form in table application angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this form:

[image]

and I would like to hide the main table:

```
name, tel, adress..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to just go out on a completely random limb here and say you're probably looking for

```
[hidden]="some Boolean statement"
```

Your other option is:

```
*ngIf="some Boolean statement"
```

Otherwise, your question is way too vague. I'd suggest maybe reading [this](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.za/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html)